# How do I create a menu item in Eclipse 4.2 that accepts contributions exactly the way Eclipse's "File > New" menu item does

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno

I want to create a menu item exactly like Eclipse's 'File > New' in my Eclipse 4 RCP application, so other Features that are built for Eclipse can contribute their "New Wizards" to it.

I've successfully done this before in an Eclipse RCP application that is based on Eclipse 3.7.  Now I'm creating an Eclipse RCP application in Eclipse 4.2 that is based on Features, and I want to use Eclipse Features such as Eclipse Java Development Tools in my RCP application.

I've created some menu items that look like the Eclipse IDE's "File > New" menu in my Application.e4xmi.  I've made sure that the ID's match the ids used in my Eclipse 4.2 IDE.

But, when I launch my RCP application, the New Java Project Wizard isn't contributed to my "File > New" menu item.

I know this sounds strange, but these are the requirements I'm working with: An RCP application that contains Features that we've built, plus Features that Eclipse has built such as the Java Development Tools.

Comment: If you want to use JDT (Java Development Tools) you'll have to switch from an Eclipse4 RCP app to a more standard RCP app that includes the 4.2 Workbench.

Comment: Paul - Thanks for the input.  Does this mean that it is not feasible to create an E4 RCP application that accepts contributions from plugins that were made to contribute to an Eclipse IDE application?